# IONIC 2 - Jwplayer integration and fullscreen mode

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, jwplayer

I'm trying to implement JwPlayer in my IONIC 2 application.

It works, but when I switch to full screen mode, the scroll bar and navigation bar remain visible. And when I switch to landscape mode, the player shrinks slightly.

So I try to play with CSS but it's not very clean

Could someone, please, helps me ?

**My template**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-card-content>
                        <div id="playerVideo"></div>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

** Part of my service **

```
jwplayer("playerVideo").setup({
    "file": replayData[0].file[0]['_'],
    "image": replayData[0].picture[0],
    "width": "100%",
    "volume": 50,
    "aspectratio": "16:9"
});
```